# C - Linked list - Insert element not updated - Only adding last input element

Tags: c, linked-list

***PREFACE***: The goal is to prompt a user for input, adding each element (input line) into a linked list.

I have been playing around with some sample code from [Learn-C.org](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists), which shows a linked list example. 
I have modified the code so that it takes "strings" instead of integers.

My **insert** function is as follows:

```
void push(node_t * head, char *data) {
    node_t * current = head;

    if(head == NULL) {
      printf("First element ever!\n");
    }
    else if(current->data == NULL) {
      current->data = data;
      current->next = NULL;

    }
    else {
      while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
        }
      current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
      current->next->data = data;
      current->next->next = NULL;
   }
}
```

Now, in MAIN, I initiate the list as follows:

```
node_t * test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Adding elements is done with:

```
  push(test_list, "FOO");
  push(test_list, "FEE");
  push(test_list, "FAA");
```

When printing the list, using **print_list(test_list)**, I get the following output:

```
FOO
FEE
FAA
```

**PROBLEM**

However, I have then included a while loop that prompts user for input and adds this to the linked list.

```
char command[120];
int counter = 0;
while(counter < 3) {
    printf("Enter element: ");
    fgets((void *)command, sizeof(command), stdin);
    push(test_list, command);   //Insert
    counter++;
}
```

However, this does not add each element into the link list. Instead, it adds the LAST element into the list three times.

For instance, when providing:

```
Enter element: Argentina
Enter element: Mexico
Enter element: Sweden
```

The list prints out as:

```
FOO
FEE
FAA
Sweden
Sweden
Sweden
```

**EDIT** (added print function)

My **print** function is as follows:

```
void print_list(node_t * head) {
    node_t * current = head;

    printf("**** Printing list ****\n");
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

What am I missing, and alternatively: How can I fix this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use `strcpy` to copy city names , pointing them using pointer may not work in this case.

Comment: `node_t * test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));test_list->data = NULL;`...`push(test_list, strdup("FAA"));push(test_list, strdup(command));`

Comment: if you print the "command" string before pushing it to list then you will see what you actually pushing and you make sure you get what you want since it works outside loop.

Comment: Debugger, logger.......................

Comment: @AhmadGhadiri I have done this, and the command content is updated correctly when printing it before push.

Comment: @northerner Can you please post your print method? I think that's where the problem is

Comment: @AhmadGhadiri updated!

Comment: @northerner sorry for late answer, I think strdup is the answer as rohit89 pointed out but also you can initialize your command in while loop each time with char* command = (char*)malloc(120*sizeof(char));. I tested and this method also works since it allocates new memory each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strdup` to return a copy of the string allocated on the heap.

> The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string s. Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).

```
node_t *test_list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
test_list->next = NULL;
test_list->data = NULL;
while(counter < 3) {
  printf("Enter element: ");
  fgets((void *)command, sizeof(command), stdin);
  push(test_list, strdup(command));   //Insert
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array `command` with capacity of 120. You use this to read in values. This is ok.

Then you send a pointer to this array to be stored. It gets stored, everything is still fine.

The next time you read input, you read it to the same array, for which you gave a pointer to be stored. So you are changing the content of the memory where that pointer points to. This is not ok.

You need to allocate separate memory areas for each string and handle their deallocations. `strdup` is the easiest way to get a new memory block with the contents of the user input.

But do remember that you really have to deallocate the memory when you don't need it anymore. In this case you might never remove any strings, but when you do, you can't just remove the element, you have to also free the memory used by the string.

Comment: Thank you. Any pointers on HOW to do this? Find memory allocation quite confusing.

Comment: @northerner It can seem like it and it is a hard subject. You should read upon the best practices on that, but one way to start is to think who "owns" the data. In this case you can assume the list "owns" the strings, so when an element is removed from the list, both the list node and the string will be `free`d. But do note that you *must not* have any pointers pointing to that node or string afterwards.

Comment: Fair enough. However, why does the code work with individual calls to push, such as push(test_list, "Hello") and push(test_list, "Bye")?
Why are these stored like HELLO - BYE and not BYE - BYE. ?

Comment: @northerner Because these are separate memory areas pointed by separate pointers. If you would do `strcpy(command, "Hello"); push(test_list, command); strcpy(command, "Bye"); push(test_list, command);` you would get *Bye* twice as you do now, because you are reusing the same memory area.

Answer (score 0):

`current->data = data;` here you are copy only pointer address not data, on that address (address of 'command') last data ('Sweden') will be available.
you should use `strcpy(current->data,data)` to copy data.